# incron and rsync not working

Tags: rsync, incron

I have incron setup and working, i can see things being logged when files are changed. 
I've tried my rsync command separately and that works fine. But when rsync in triggered by incron, nothing happens. i explicitly stated all the paths i could see.

**here is my incrontab -e**

```
/home/dir/dir/ IN_MODIFY sudo rsync -pogr -e 'ssh -i /root/.ssh/rsasync1' /home/dir/dir/* root@ipaddress:/home/dir/dir/
```

i'm working as root right now and executing the command as root. also tried /usr/bin/rsync and that didn't work in addition to sudo rsync etc...

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in incrontab:

```
/home/dir/dir/ IN_MODIFY sudo rsync -pogr -e ssh -i /root/.ssh/rsasync1 /home/dir/dir/* root@ipaddress:/home/dir/dir/
```

In above command I have removed the quotes. Incrontab can not run with  Single quote OR double quote.

Remember: Pleas keep the quote while executing in terminal.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i forgot about this thread, hopefully it helps someone else in the future